# Authorization in FastAPI with multiple JWT flows and scopes

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, fastapi

I'm trying to implement a FastAPI application with two authentication/authorization flows:

1. `Users API`: users can create an account and then authenticate (login) with their credentials to receive a JWT `user token`. Users can then send the `user token` to the application and interact with the `Users API`.
2. `Stores API`: users can send the `user token` from above and request a JWT `store token`, which includes the scopes/permissions allowed for them for that specific store. Users can then send the `store token` and interact with `Stores API`.

Following the FastAPI [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/#global-view) I was able to implement the auth flow for the `Users API`.

How can I implement the auth flow for the `Stores API`? More specifically, how can I tell FastAPI that to request a `store token`, users need to be authenticated in the `Users API` and the token they receive should be used to get a new access token, for the `Stores API`.

I tried using the following oauth2 code flow but I'm not sure if its the correct way:

```
from fastapi.security import OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer

oauth2_store = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl="users/token",
    tokenUrl="users/token"
)

@app.post("/stores/auth/{store_id}")
def create_store_token(store_id: str, user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]):
    store_token = create_store_token(store_id, user)
    return store_token

@app.get("/stores/items/{store_id}")
def get_store_items(store: Annotated[Store, Security(get_current_store, scopes=["store:items"])]):
    return store.items
```

Where `get_current_store` is similar to `get_current_user` in the tutorial (Decodes the store token and retrieves the relevant store from the database).

I think the issue lies with the `oauth2_store` definition. I'm not sure how to reference the `Users API` from the same application.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.